# Remove item from shell "Send To" menu

Tags: delphi, shell, contextmenu

I have used this
http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/create_lnk.htm

It worked fine but I used a test "send to link" and now would like to remove it so I can add a link for the program I am about to write.

Can someone please point me at some code that will reverse the above procedure? Or tell me what changes to make to the current code to make another procedure for Remove.

{grin} Yeah, I know, I should have looked for that before adding it. I guess I can do a System Recovery, but remove would be nicer.

Comment: A better question would be one that asked for clarification about the method that created the link in the first place.  What parts of that method do you not understand?  If you can answer those questions, undo-ing the action becomes trivial *and* you learn something rather than just copying and pasting more code you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

All you've done is create a shortcut file named `LinkName`. So, you simply need to delete that file by calling `DeleteFile(LinkName)`.